# How to compute the quadratic form of 2 matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Given 2 matrix *A*, *B* with the same dimension,

```
M(x, y) = |A(x, y).*A(x, y)  A(x, y).*B(x, y)|
          |A(x, y).*B(x, y)  B(x, y).*B(x, y)|
```

How to get the *M* in matlab?

**updated**

Hopefully, we can get a *M* with dimension (m, n, 2, 2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this is a straightforward way to do it:

```
M = [ A.*A  A.*B ; A.*B B.*B ]
```

Or did you have something more optimized in mind?

**[Edit]** If I understand correctly, you want a 4D result. Here is my ugly solution:

```
M = reshape([A(:).*A(:) ; A(:).*B(:) ; A(:).*B(:) ; B(:).*B(:)], [size(A) 2 2])
```

Comment: No any optimization :) I am just wondering if we can get a *M* with dimension (m, n, 2, 2) from *A, B*? The code you suggest is great but it will generate a 8x8 matrix.